# Google print options have changed again

Tags: browser, printing

Yesterday the Google print option sidebar changed.  I can no longer adjust margin sizes or font size from "more settings".
Does anyone know how to change margin sizes and font size now from the Google browser print option?

Answer (score 0):

Margins can be adjusted by going to `More Settings -> Margins -> Custom`. The font size is adjusted by using the `Scale` option. In some cases you can't adjust one or the other, or possibly both. The screenshots below are taken with Chrome v74.0.3729.108

> Ability to adjust Margins and Scale on a eBay print

[image]

> Unable to adjust margins on a PDF document printed through Chrome

[image]